# How to prevent mouseleave from firing on right-click in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, contextmenu

A few versions back, Chrome started firing the `mouseleave` event as soon as you right-click to open the context menu. This makes attempting to inspect elements which only appear during hover (e.g. navigation menus) extremely frustrating, since it becomes impossible to use right-click -> Inspect Element. Safari doesn't do this, and Firefox only fires mouseleave when you move the mouse into the content menu (which is essentially just as bad).

Is there any way I can regain my ability to easily inspect hover-displayed elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To inspect you can use f12 then select your element by hovering over it. You could stop the onMouseLeave event possible by using stopPropogation but it is'nt going to keep the onHover going.

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know about the hotkey to activate "inspect mode" or whatever that is. Using that, combined with a little trick to let me mouse my mouse into the inspector without triggering mouseleave, makes it possible to properly inspect my menus! Thank you!

Comment: of course. Please don't forget to choose this as the correct answer if you are satisfied that it has answered your question. And yes most browsers i believe to include (Safari, IE9,FF, Chrome) all use F12 to open the developer console.